# How do I refer to a combobox object using a variable?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

This code resides in my the event code of my Access form. 
I'm trying to replace the name of the ComboBox in the 3rd line of the code below with a variable. The code works when I use the name of the ComboBox, but gives me "method or data member not found" error when I try to use a variable. I have several ComboBoxes and like to run the third line below in a loop for all of the ComboBoxes.

I think the question boils down to how do I set the variable "ComboBoxName" equal to the object cboComboBox and not the value that is currently in cboComboBox (which is currently ""). This is the code that is not working:

```
Dim ComboBoxName As ComboBox
Set ComboBoxName = Me.cboComboBox
Me.ComboBoxName.RowSource = ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I set the variable "ComboBoxName" equal to the object
>   cboComboBox

It would either be:

```
Dim ComboBoxName As ComboBox
Set ComboBoxName = Me!cboComboBox
ComboBoxName.RowSource = ""
```

or:

```
Dim ComboBoxName As String
ComboBoxName = Me!cboComboBox.Name
Me(ComboBoxName).RowSource = ""
```

Comment: I have several comboboxes and fill them with the same algorithm, therefore using a function - `Function helper(comboname)`. Can I make the combobox name "dynamic", calling it in the function `Sheets(3).comboname.List = "value1"?

Comment: Yes, something like the last code line in my answer.

Comment: I wonder if I need `activex` combobox as I need the name for reference. With a normal combobox, there is no naming reference possible?

Comment: @Timo: Sorry, don't follow. You can reference any control by its name.